# How to make button full width in Bootstrap 3 input-group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use `input-group` to display input for quantity, "Qty." label and "Add to basket" button - all inline. `input-group` goes full width as expected.

How to make input with fixed width (40 pixels) and make button full width? Default behaviour is full width for input (not button). in my case is not useful as I want to have input for quantity small and button as big as possible.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (rounded to the nearest dollar)" style="width: 40px; float: right;">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Qty.</span>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button aria-label="Add" name="inWarenkorb" type="submit" value="Add" class="submit btn btn-primary" style="width:100%">
      <span>Add to basket</span>
    </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/d53g68hw/

Answer (score 0):

You can override CSS on the input-group from display: table to display: block. on the input-group-btn from width: 1% to width:100% and display: block.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the Button `input-group-btn` a width of 100%

```
.input-group-btn{
 width: 100%
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ex7rbhpw/1/

Your Input Group (`input-group`) uses `display: table` so we just set one "cell" (your span with the class `input-group-btn`) to the maximum width of 100%. 
Your button will not take the full 100% because the other "cells" (your span-tags) have a minimum width, content or/and padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you are looking for using `display: table` for the `input-group` container and `display: table-cell` for its child elements. Example:

```
.input-group > * {  
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.input-group > * {  
  display: table-cell;
}

.input-group > .form-control, .input-group > .input-group-addon {
  width: 40px;
}
.input-group > .input-group-btn, .input-group > .input-group-btn > button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use block level button which is as shown below

> ```
> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"> button</button>
> ```